# I will send cards to my friends to(or for) wish them a happy New Year

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I will send cards to my friends **to** wish them a Happy New Year.

I will send cards to my friends **for** wish them a Happy New Year.

May I replace the preposition“ to” with“ for”?

Does this make any difference? The original sentence uses **to** as a preposition, but I don't quite understand why to use **to** here, I think the expression of **for** will be more in line with the actual content.
Thanks for parsing

Comment: No you can't. The infinitive **to wish** is necessary in this construction. **for wish** is not grammatical. But you could send them cards **for their birthdays**.

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could use the construction **for the purpose of wishing**, but that is overly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. In your original sentence, "to" is part of a verb phrase and not a preposition. The infinitive *to wish* is grammatical in this construction; *for wish* is ungrammatical whether you consider "wish" a verb or a noun.

But you could send them cards for their birthdays.